# DataGridView Manipulation in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

It's my first time working with vb and I have to make a grid with 10 columns and a variable number of rows and display data on the cells.

```
 DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = True


 Dim numColumns As Integer
 If Integer.TryParse(word.Text, numColumns) AndAlso numColumns > 0 Then
     DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
     For i As Integer = 1 To 10
         Dim newColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
         newColumn.HeaderText = i - 1
         newColumn.ReadOnly = True
         DataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn)
     Next
     For i As Integer = 0 To numColumns - 1
         If i Mod 10 = 0 AndAlso i > 0 Then
             If DataGridView1.RowCount <= i \ 10 Then
                 DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
             End If
         End If
         If DataGridView1.RowCount > i \ 10 Then
             Dim index As Integer = i Mod 10
             If index >= 0 And index < DataGridView1.ColumnCount Then
                 DataGridView1.Rows(i \ 10).Cells(index).Value = i
             End If
         End If
     Next
 Else
     MsgBox("Insira um valor valido e positivo para o número de DM's")
 End If
```

[image: program]

I tried different numbers and some chatgpt/blackbox but it didnt solve anything

Comment: I can't tell from this what you want to add as row data. You defined the columns, but I think you want to declare a row, populating it with data, then add the row to the `DataGridView1`. It also looks like `numColumns` is misleading; shouldn't that be `numRows`?

Comment: Don't manipulate the DataGridView columns and rows. Create a data source (i.e. DataSet, `List (Of T)`, etc.) that contains the data. Then, bind that to the DataGridView for *display* (`DataGridView1.DataSource = <your data source>`. Then, if you manipulate the data source, the DGV will automatically update to reflect the data changes.

Comment: Edited your question title. A `DataGrid` is an ASP.NET control, while a `DataGridView` is a Windows Forms control.

Comment: Why are you doing stuff like this: `If i Mod 10 = 0 AndAlso i > 0 Then`

Comment: I appreciate the help but I got it

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try
        If Not IsNothing(_comandosFinsPLC) AndAlso _LigacaoPLC_ON = True Then
            Dim sinal As TipoSinal
            If cmbTipoSinal.Text = "Sem Sinal" Then
                sinal = TipoSinal.SemSinal
            Else
                sinal = TipoSinal.ComSinal
            End If
            Dim dados() = _comandosFinsPLC.LerDM(Val(dm.Text), Val(word.Text), ObterTipoVariavel(), TipoDado.TipoDadoMemoria.DM, sinal)



            Dim a As Integer
            Dim b As Integer

            If Integer.TryParse(word.Text, a) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(dm.Text, b) Then

                Dim DMs As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(word.Text)

                DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False

                DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

                Dim cellCount As Integer = 0

                For i As Integer = 0 To 10


                    Dim newColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()

                    If i = 0 Then
                        newColumn.HeaderText = "DM"
                    Else
                        newColumn.HeaderText = i - 1
                        newColumn.ReadOnly = True
                    End If

                    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(newColumn)
                Next
                Dim _index_dados As Integer = 0

                For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(word.Text) / 11 + 1

                    If cellCount Mod 10 = 0 AndAlso DMs - cellCount > 0 Then

                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                    End If

                    For j As Integer = 0 To 10
                        If DMs = cellCount Then
                            Exit For
                        End If

                        If j = 0 Then
                            If i = 0 Then

                                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = dm.Text
                            Else
                                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = dm.Text + 10 * i
                            End If

                        Else



                            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = dados(_index_dados)

                            _index_dados += 1



                            cellCount += 1

                        End If
                    Next
                Next
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This answer does not use data binding to the data grid view
If you ask why it is because I have more control how the DGV looks
These two functions are called when the form loads StyleDGV & ViewSearches

```
 Private Sub frmViewTX_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    StyleDGV()
    ViewSearches()

End Sub

    Private Sub StyleDGV()

    'Set Design of the DataGridView
    dgvTX.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 13.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
    dgvTX.ColumnCount = 8
    dgvTX.Columns(0).Width = 50   'ID
    dgvTX.Columns(1).Width = 140  'Date
    dgvTX.Columns(2).Width = 136  'TxType
    dgvTX.Columns(3).Width = 120  'Amt
    dgvTX.Columns(4).Width = 114  'ckNum
    dgvTX.Columns(5).Width = 390  'Desc
    dgvTX.Columns(6).Width = 130  'Bal
    dgvTX.Columns(7).Width = 10  'dumbS
    'To Set Col Header Size Mode = Enabled
    'To Set Col Header Default Cell Styles DO in Properties
    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"


    dgvTX.ColumnHeadersHeight = 10 'Sans Serif 'Tahoma
    dgvTX.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold)

    dgvTX.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    dgvTX.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
    dgvTX.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    dgvTX.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight


    'dgvTX.Enabled = False 'Prevents Selection of data and scrolling
    'DGV Header Names
    dgvTX.Columns(0).Name = "TID"
    dgvTX.Columns(1).Name = "  Date"
    dgvTX.Columns(2).Name = "  Tx Type"
    dgvTX.Columns(3).Name = "  Amount"
    dgvTX.Columns(4).Name = "  CK Num"
    dgvTX.Columns(5).Name = "Desctiption"
    dgvTX.Columns(6).Name = "  Balance"
    dgvTX.Columns(7).Name = "     "


    dgvTX.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(3).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(4).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(5).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvTX.Columns(6).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable

End Sub

Private Sub ViewSearches()

    Dim intID As Integer
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strTxType As String
    Dim strAmt As Decimal
    Dim strCKNum As String
    Dim strDesc As String
    Dim strBal As Decimal
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim maxRowCount As Integer
    Dim emptyStr As String = "  "

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)

            If gvSearchType = "All" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData"
            ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoRangeYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth >= $gvFromMonth AND txSearchMonth <= $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth BETWEEN $gvFromMonth AND $gvToMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvToMonth", gvToMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            ElseIf gvSearchType = "MoYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txSearchMonth = $gvFromMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            ElseIf gvSearchType = "TxMoYr" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txType = $gvTxType AND txSearchMonth = $gvFromMonth AND txYear = $gvYear "
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvTxType", gvTxType)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvFromMonth", gvFromMonth)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)

            ElseIf gvSearchType = "Year" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TxData WHERE txYear = $gvYear"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$gvYear", gvYear)
            End If


            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvTX.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above is when DB is bound to dgvTX
                '============================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("TID")))
                    strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString 'txSearchMonth '
                    strTxType = rdr("txType").ToString
                    strAmt = CDec(rdr("txAmount"))
                    strCKNum = rdr("txCKNum").ToString
                    strDesc = rdr("txDesc").ToString
                    strBal = CDec(rdr("txBalance"))
                    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    'dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"'Adds the $ sign and commas
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(intID, strDate, strTxType, strAmt, strCKNum, strDesc, strBal, emptyStr)

                    rowCount = rowCount + 1

                End While

                dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                dgvTX.Sort(dgvTX.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
            End Using

            If rowCount <= 25 Then
                maxRowCount = 25 - rowCount
                For iA = 1 To maxRowCount
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(" ")
                Next
            End If


            lblAmt.Text = $"Current Balance  {Date.Today:MMMM d yyyy}"
            Dim dateToday = Date.Today
            Dim lblDate As String = dateToday.ToString("MMM" & " " & "d" & " " & "yyyy")
            lblAmt.Text = "Current Balance  " & lblDate

            GetCBBalance()

            tbBal.Text = "$ " & String.Format("{0:n}", strTotalBal)

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: *"This answer does not use data binding [...] because I have more control how the DGV looks"*. That is utterly untrue. You have exactly the same amount of control over how the grid looks whether you use data-binding or not. If you allow the grid to generate the columns when you bind then you will have to configure them after that. You can create the columns yourself and still use data-binding though. You simply set the `DataPropertyName` of the columns you create so they know which column/property of the data source to bind to. You can do all that in the designer.

Comment: This is not really an answer as it stands, IMO. Suggest you limit the code in the answer to the part where you load the DGV. Styling has nothing to do with the OP's question.